# Error in importing javascript function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap carousel` in my web page, but console shows this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
```

I have imported `bootstrap.js` and `jquery-1.8.3.min.js`, but the carousel does not slides on page load, now I am unable to understand what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 2000
        })
    </script>
```

body syntax:

```
<div>
    <center>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:800px; height:400px;">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item"><img style="width:800px; height:400px" src="img/c4.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Heading</h4>
                    <p>like never before...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img style="width:800px; height:400px" src="img/c3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img style="width:800px; height:400px" src="img/c3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img style="width:800px; height:400px" src="img/c4.jpg"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your script references? Your error typically means that one of the jQuery libs failed to load, or are being loaded in the wrong order.

Comment: Any chance that your code executes before jQuery carousel files loading? try to wrap your code with jquery dom ready.

Comment: have you tried importing jQuery before bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Import jQuery before bootstrap. bootstrap.js builds ontop of jQuery so you will need it to be loaded before bootstrap initializes:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000
    })
</script>
```